# The name does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window {
    public static ABClient client;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        client=new ABClient();
        client.Connect();
    }
}

class B {
    public B() {
        client.Connect();  // The name 'client' does not exist in the current context
    }
}
```

Why do I get this compile error if client is public? I need to have one client which would be accessible from any other window or class. Please help with the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call it this way :

```
MainWindow.client.Connect();
```

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid mistake. That's because I used to learn on console apps.